# ZFS deduplication

Tags: zfs, deduplication

This is my first post on this website so please be kind with me :)

On Centos 7, using ZFS deduplication in the past on a storage pool, I moved all file-systems that dedup was on to another storage pool.

But, doing a "zpool status -D " I can see that deduplication is still in use on this pool.

I think that, if deduplication was ON on a file-system in the past, then changed to off, but in meantime some snapshot were taken, the deduplication is there, and there are no possibility to know exactly where it is coming from....

Am I right? is there any possibility to know if deduplication is in use on snapshots ?

Thanks for your help and sorry in advance if this is not the best place to post this issue...

Regards, Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to completely get rid of deduplication once it has been enabled - at the very least the root node of the DDT will remain present even when the last file using a reduplicated block has been removed.